# How JSON format affects storage and capacity units

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have this rudimentary question about DynamoDb -- is it worth shortening attribute names and removing whitespace in order to save on throughput and storage?

I am planning to store millions of items that looks like this:

```
{
  "currency": "USD",
  "openPrice": 0.1,
  "closePrice": 0.1,
  "highPrice": 0.1,
  "lowPrice": 0.1
}
```

if I reformat this JSON fragment to look like this:

```
{"c":"USD","op":0.1,"cp":0.1,"hp":0.1,"lp":0.1}
```

would this shorter JSON result in cost savings because of lower storage and fewer throughput capacity units?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, it would save the capacity units. However, you can't make out anything with the above attribute names. If it is a one off or very short life span solution, you can go ahead with that. Otherwise, it would be difficult to manage the above data model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, attribute names are factored into the total item size. This becomes important in one of two scenarios:

1. If your access patterns involve scans; or queries that expect to retrieve many items - because in these cases you get billed for aggregated size (ie sum of all accessed items) so small items use consumed capacity more efficiently than larger items
2. If you have items with many attributes such that the size of the attribute names and the size of their values pushes the total item size past the 1KB boundary - this is important because write capacity is billed in 1KB increments

I would use common sense in naming: prefer short and concise naming but try to avoid cryptic names (e.g. `c` is not a great name, but neither is `customerDataItemIdentifier` - a better choice might be `custId`)

Comment: Maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400KB, not 1KB.

Comment: There is also another reason why it matters for scans and queries: There is limited of returned data of at max 1MB per call.

Comment: @Dunedan yes, but capacity is billed in increments of 1KB for writes and 4KB for reads. So, while an item may be up to 400 KB in size, it’s hard to imagine attributes names contributing much relatively speaking. However, attribute names can easily push an item over the 1KB threshold which would cause a single item to consume 2 capacity units to write as opposed to just one.